# Should I worry about long avg page load time on Google Analytics for visitors from India?

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed

For a particular day, Site Speed Page Timings in Google Analytic is 23.77 Secs. I selected that particular day and used Day mode to see timing hourly.

There when I Added City as 2nd filter then I saw most of them are accessed from India or nearby locations which are very slow. Others are 0 secs.

In India, visitors connection speed can be slow. **Should I worry about page load timing in this case?** As seen on snap, 1133 pages has been accessed by Google and only around 35 pages got bad Avg Page Load timing.

When I used to see bad Page Load Timing then I used to think of my Hosting provider but from the data, I think it is not of Hosting Provider!

[image: Page Timing - Avg page load time]

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad idea to check [Googe Site Speed Tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and optimize your site. If your site is optimized you don't have to worry about those load times. You can't do anything about your users slow Internet, but you can move your data near them for example by using a CDN. However, using CDN won't make the load time much faster as the bottleneck for users with slow Internet is not RTT. Anyways, if I were in your shoes I would optimize my site and then just do nothing!

Comment: I am also not sure about those timing. Is it based on Visitors internet speed or not?

Comment: Yes, it is based on visitors Internet.